# Remove an item from listbox and update value accordingly

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a button that removes a value from a listbox but i have a method that removes with the value that it has stored.

How do i take the value of selected item and put it in the method?

```
   private void putBack_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = shoppingKart_listBox.GetItemText(shoppingKart_listBox.SelectedItem);

        for (int n = shoppingKart_listBox.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
        {
            if (shoppingKart_listBox.Items[n].ToString().Contains(text))
            {
                shoppingKart_listBox.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                shopping.putBack(text) // ??
            }
        }
    }
```

and the method itself

```
    public void putBack(Item itemToPutBack)
    {
        amountLeft += itemToPutBack.price;
        items.Remove(itemToPutBack);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Store reference before deleting item from list:

```
if (shoppingKart_listBox.Items[n].ToString().Contains(text))
{
    var item = shoppingKart_listBox.Items[n];
    shoppingKart_listBox.Items.RemoveAt(n);
    shopping.putBack(item);
}
```